Stripe subscription integration issue in Flutter app: Client secret format error
Describe the bug
We have implemented Stripe payment integration on our website using the checkout method. This includes creating customers and subscriptions, and storing the Checkout ID in our database.
Current Implementation
For our Flutter application, we replicated the backend system to create customers and checkouts. We generate a checkout session and retrieve the client secret to be passed to the Flutter app.
Issue
When the Flutter developer attempts to use this client secret on the mobile app, an error is encountered stating that the secret's format does not match the expected client secret formatting.
This is how i am generating Client secret and creating checkout session using php
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_key');
$clientReferenceId = $customerid.'_'.time();
try {
    $result = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
        'customer' => $customerid,
        'line_items' => [[
            'price' => $planpriceid,
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'subscription',
        'success_url' => 'https://domain.app/plan_success_data.php?company_id=&plan_id=&no_of_workers=',
         'cancel_url' => 'https://domain.app/plan_failed.php',

         'client_reference_id' => $clientReferenceId,
         
       
        
       
    ]);
    if(isset($result->id))
    {




       $subId=$result->id;
            $clientSecret = $result->client_secret->id; // Get client_secret from Stripe response

        $data = [ 
            "status" => true,
           
            "stripe_sub_id" => $subId,
             "client_reference_id" => $result->client_reference_id,
             "client_secret" => $result->client_secret
        ];
                  echo  json_encode($data);

  }
  else
  {
     $data = [
                "status" => false,
                "stripe_sub_id"=>''
                
                ];
                  echo  json_encode($data);
  }
}
 catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
    // Handle any exceptions
    echo json_encode(["status" => false, "error" => $e->getMessage()]);
}

when i pass this client secret to flutter get this error
Error Message

flutter: exception StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: "secret format does not match expected client secret formatting.", message: "secret format does not match expected client secret formatting.", stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))
Client Secret Example
secret-cus_P89GSD6zWgADp6_1718266392_1718266392

Backend Technology
The backend is implemented in PHP.
Request
Please advise on the correct method to implement Stripe subscription integration using the checkout method in our Flutter app, ensuring the system works with the Stripe checkout ID.
we tried different-2 way still facing same issue

I do not see you pass the ui_mode when creating the Session, https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/embedded/quickstart which has the client_secret in the response. Then, you would want to log the client_secret while testing to ensure that you see the expected valued there.

show the flutter code rather than the php

@sh1hab await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
paymentSheetParameters: const SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
paymentIntentClientSecret: "cus_P89GSD6zWgAD92",
customerId: data['customer'],
allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true, // set this to true
customerEphemeralKeySecret: data['ephemeralKey'],
googlePay: PaymentSheetGooglePay(
testEnv: true, currencyCode: "USD", merchantCountryCode: "IN"),
merchantDisplayName: 'CRESOL',
),
);
